# If $\phi :G\rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism and $G$ is soluble, then $Im(\phi)$ is also soluble

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

If $\phi :G\rightarrow H$ is a group homomorphism and $G$ is soluble, then $Im(\phi)$ is also soluble,

I tried creating a map $\psi:G\rightarrow Im(\phi)$, such that $\psi(g)=\phi(g)$, where $g\in G$. Clearly the map is surjective, but how can I show that it's injective. By doing so, I get that $G\cong Im(\phi)$. Would this be enough to show that $Im(\phi)$ is soluble.

Comment: An arbitrary group homomorphism is clearly not injective.

Comment: Have you heard about *quotient group* and *first isomorphism theorem*?

Comment: yes, but why would that imply that the group homomorphism isn't injective. I thought that if $\phi(g)=\phi(h)$, then $\phi(g)-\phi(h)=\phi(g-h)=0$. And so, $g-h=0$ which implies $g=h$

Comment: By the way, even if *soluble* is sometimes used, one generally rathers says *solvable*.

Comment: Using additive notation isn't helpful, but in any case, if we have $\phi(g) = \phi(h)$ then all we can conclude is that $gh^{-1} \in {\rm ker} \phi$. It need not be the case that ${\rm ker} \phi = \{1_{G} \}.$

Comment: @Berci ah I see, by the first isomorphism theorem $G/ker(\phi)\cong Im(\phi)$ and we know $G/ker(\phi)$ is soluble, hence so must $Im(\phi)$

Comment: Yes, once you know that any quotient group is solvable, you're done by the First Isom.Thm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that $\phi(G')=\phi(G)'$.

Observe that $\phi(xyx^{-1}y^{-1})=\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(x)^{-1}\phi(y)^{-1}$. Hence the result follows.

**Edit:** If $$\phi(G')=\phi(G)'$$ then
$$\phi(G^r)=\phi(G)^r$$. By $G^r$ I mean $r$ th commutater subgroup of $G$.

Since $G$ is solvable, $G^n=1$ for some $n\implies 1=\phi(G^n)=\phi(G)^n$. Hence $\phi(G)$ is solvable.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by $G'$

Comment: @AndrewBrick: The Commutator subgroup. Check this. Generally defination of solvable groups is done by derived series. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup

Comment: So if $\phi(G')=\phi(G)'$, then how does this show that $Im(\phi)$ is soluble. Sorry if the question seems obvious

Comment: @AndrewBrick: Ok. I will edit my answer by giving details.

Comment: Ah I see, I've haven't really come across this theorem, that $G$ is solvable $\iff$ $G^n=1$ for some $n$

Comment: By the $r$th commutater subgroup of $G$, you mean the group $r^{-1}Gr$ right?

Comment: @AndrewBrick: $G'=<\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}|x,y\in G\}>$ Then $G'$ is called as Commutator subgroup of $G$. $G'$ has many property; $G/G'$ must be an abelian group for example. $G^2=G''$ i.e Commutator of the commutator groups. Hence, $G^r=G'''''''...$. Notice that $G^r/G^{r+1}$ is abelian. Hence $G\geq G'\geq ... G^r\geq ..$ is an composition series. Hence  when $G$ is solvable $G^n$ reach the identity.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

That $G$ is solvable means that it has a composition series with abelian quotients.

If you start with a composition series for $G$, how can you get one for $im(\phi)$?

Comment: So if $1\subset G_1\subset...\subset G_n=G$ is a composition series for $G$, then how can I get one for $Im(\phi)$

Comment: @AndrewBrick Try applying $\phi$ to each part of the series.

Answer (score 1):

$$\textrm{Ker}(\phi) \leq G$$

$$[G: \textrm{Ker}(\phi)] \simeq \textrm{Im}(\phi)$$

Quotient groups of solvable groups are solvable, so we are done